# How to access element in XUL overlay through javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have loaded a plugin into my XUL overlay, by

```
<vbox style="height:0;">
    <html:embed type="application/x-my-plugin" id="my-plugin" style="height:0;"/>
</vbox>
```

Now an event triggers when the user loads a new tab and I have a reference to the caller. This is done through javascript, which is attached to the XUL overlay.

```
var caller = myEvent.originalTarget;
```

When I try to do the following, my variable "plugin" is null. What could be the problem and how can I solve the issue?

```
var plugin = caller.getElementById("my-plugin");
plugin.calculateTime();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your real code uses `document.getElementById` rather than `caller.getElementById`. If `document.getElementById` returns `null` then the element with this ID is definitely not in the document. This can have two reasons:

1. You are accessing the document too early and it didn't finish loading. You should generally never access the DOM before the `load` event, it can cause various issues. However, if your code runs from the `TabOpen` event then this shouldn't be the issue.
2. When your overlay was merged into the browser window this particular element was skipped. Elements at the top-level of the overlay will be ignored if they don't have an ID or their ID isn't found in the document. In order to have your element considered your overlay should look like this:

```xml
<overlay ...>
  <window id="main-window">
    <vbox collapsed="true">
      <html:embed .../>
    </vbox>
  </window>
</overlay>
```

`main-window` is the ID of the root element of `browser.xul` so that your element will be inserted at the top level. Note that I used the [`collapsed` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/collapsed), that's better than setting the `height` style if you need an element that doesn't occupy any space but is still initialized.

Comment: Thanks boss, that makes more sense now.